# Setting up static ip with wireless N USB adapter (TL-WN723N) ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, usb, static-ip

I'm trying to set up static ip on my computer that uses a wifi usb adapter, specifically TL-WN723N.

I have not installed its driver because it was working fine after plugging in

i added these to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlx18d6c7095b6a
iface wlx18d6c7095b6a inet static
address 192.168.0.151
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and then

```
sudo ip address flush wlx18d6c7095b6a && sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```

As a result, the wifi icon changed to up and down arrows and i get disconnected from my router.

If i go to system settings > Network, i see my access point is listed as out of range, but other devices can connect to it fine.

I had to remove the static ip settings and reboot the computer to get the wifi adapter working again

Wireless details

```
sudo lshw -class network

*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@2:3
   logical name: wlx18d6c7095b6a
   serial: 18:d6:c7:09:5b:6a
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.0.12 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn


lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Found the solution!
https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-add-wireless-lan-adaptor-static-ip-ubuntu-auto-connects-startup.
Just follow the guide in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!
https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-add-wireless-lan-adaptor-static-ip-ubuntu-auto-connects-startup.
Just follow the guide in the link.