# How to permanently set a static IP address for a USB Ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, usb, 22.04, ethernet

On Ubuntu 22.04.2 I am using a USB-Ethernet adapter with the identifier `enx00e04c680202` which shows up in `ifconfig`:

```
enx00e04c680202: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to set a static IP address for this adapter to 192.168.200.100, which should be the same after a reboot. I always want this adapter `enx00e04c680202` to have the static IP address 192.168.200.100 even when I reboot the laptop.

Following an answer given [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920963/setting-up-static-ip-with-wireless-n-usb-adapter-tl-wn723n-ubuntu-16-04-2) I added a file `/etc/network/interfaces` with the following content:

```
iface enx00e04c680202 inet static 
    address 192.168.200.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.200.255
```

However, if I now set the IP address of that adapter manually to 192.168.200.100 using the command

```
sudo ifconfig enx00e04c680202 192.168.200.100
```

or restart the network and reboot the laptop, the IP address of the above adapter might be the same(!) or is changed (see the example of the output of `ifconfig` above -> IP address is NOT 192.168.200.100).

So how to fix this problem? How to make sure that after every reboot/power off and power on the IP address of the adapter `enx00e04c680202` is 192.168.200.100?

**Additional information**

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

There is no other file in `/etc/netplan/`.

In addition, in the network settings this adapter is not even activated:

[image]

but it works! I can connect to connected devices on that adapter. I do not understand how I can connect if it is not activated???

Comment: Do you get the same results if you undo the changes in the config and try the GUI settings? Click on the "cog" icon and go to the IPv4 tab and set it to manual and enter your static IP settings.

Comment: Have you tried *editing* the connection settings for that device to set the static IP and routes?

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, I edited the file `/etc/network/interfaces` as mentioned in my question ...

Comment: @Alex no, I mean in Network Manager.  `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated and if you're using Network Manager as it is clear you are with a desktop GUI you should ALWAYS configure in Network Manager not `/etc/network/interfaces`.  Remove your entry in `/etc/network/interfaces` and configure it in Network Manager, not the `/etc/network/interfaces` (ifupdown) or any CLI settings files.